# algorithm to calculate XOR

Tags: algorithm, xor

I want to calculate XOR of numbers from 0 to (n)^{1/2} - 1 with each of numbers from 0 to (n)^{1/2} - 1.
i want to do this in O(n) time and cant use the XOR, OR, AND operations.

If i know the XOR of X and Y, can i calculate XOR of X+1 and Y in constant time?

As some have pointed out that XOR can be calculated in constant time using AND and NOT.
How do i do the same for AND?
How do i calculate AND of numbers from 0 to (n)^{1/2} - 1 with each of numbers from 0 to (n)^{1/2} - 1.
i want to do this in O(n) time and cant use the XOR, OR, AND operations.

P.S. - RAM model is being assumed here and operations (add, multiply, divide) on < log(n) bit numbers can be done is constant time.

Comment: Why can't you use xor?  What operators are you allowed to use instead?

Comment: Is this "homework"? If yes, you should tag it accordingly.

Comment: The output contains O(n.log(n)) bits making it impossible to generate in O(n) time.

Comment: @Paul: How can the output contain O(n log n) bits? The highest number it's dealing with is root n...

Comment: @Jon root n contains log(root n) = log(n)/2 bits. The output's a table of sqrt(n) * sqrt(n) numbers (ie, n numbers) each with O(log n) bits.

Comment: @Paul: Ah... I'd interpreted the question differently, just XORing the numbers from 0 to root n, once. It's not terribly clear :) In your reading of the question, I totally agree.

Comment: @Jon I think with your interpretation of the question I'm sure it can be done better than O(n).

Comment: @jon and @Paul - I am sorry, i dint state the question correctly. RAM model is being assumed here and operations (add, multiply, divide) on < log(n) bit numbers can be done is constant time.

Comment: Remember that if you sum 2 bits and ignore the carry, you have the XOR. So 0+0=0, 0+1=1, 1+0=1, 1+1=0 (with carry). If you use this, division and remainder you can easily build the XOR.

Comment: Note near duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057216/algorithm-to-calculate-and

Comment: @Paul: If addition can be done in constant time (as the OP has specified), then the whole thing *can* be done in O(n), as you only need to calculate one new bit per output element.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Start with a [1x1] grid:

```
H(-1) = [ 0 ]
```

Then apply the recursion:

```
H(i) = [ H(i-1)           H(i-1)+(1 << i)
         H(i-1)+(1 << i)  H(i-1)          ]
```

where that denotes matrix concatenation.  i.e. each recursion doubles the size of the grid in each dimension.  Repeat until you achieve the required size.

Comment: Nice answer. I found a much more complicated way to do it.

Comment: @xanatos: Yes it works!  I doubt it has a name!  There's really not a lot of magic going on here; I'm simply calculating the XOR function independently for each bit position, and then spreading the results across all positions in the output array.  (If you rewrite `H(i-1)` as `H(i-1)+(0 << i)` in my answer, it should perhaps make it more obvious why it works.)

Answer (score 2):

You can build an XOR gate from NANDs (diagram [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/XOR_from_NAND.svg/300px-XOR_from_NAND.svg.png)), so you could do it with an `if` statement with `!` (NOT) and `&&` AND (if we use C/C++/PHP as an example here). As for working it out in a constant time, the calculation is the same every iteration, so it will be constant.

Comment: I think the point is that this approach calculates results one bit at a time.  There are *n.log(n)* bits in the output matrix, so this will not be *O(n)*.

Answer (score 2):

A XOR can be built using AND and NOT (and combining them to build a NAND). Can you use AND and NOT?

In C#:

```
Func<bool, bool, bool> nand = (p, q) => !(p && q);

Func<bool, bool, bool> xor = (p, q) =>
{
    var s1 = nand(p, q);
    var s2a = nand(p, s1);
    var s2b = nand(q, s1);
    return nand(s2a, s2b);
};
```

I'm mimicking this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic#XOR

In C#, using modulus, sum and multiply.
(Limits: I'm using uint, so max 32 bits. It will work for ulong, so max 64 bits)

```
uint a = 16;
uint b = 5;
uint mult = 1;
uint res = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    uint i1 = a % 2;
    uint i2 = b % 2;

    if (i1 != i2) {
        res += mult;
    }

    a /= 2;
    b /= 2;
    mult *= 2;
}
```

Where res is the response.

Modulus can be built on top of division, multiplication and subtraction.

Comment: I don't have any problem if someone doesn't like my reply, but whoever gave me a -1 should at least tell me what I did wrong. Yes, I do know that mine isn't a perfect solution, but considering that the OP is probably asking an "academic" or "homework" question, I don't think the response must be "the most beautiful in the world"

Comment: The problem is that your solution doesn't answer the question correctly. You have implemented xor using a bit-by-bit approach which yields an O(n.log(n)) solution. The question was to find an O(n) solution (although admittedly the question wasn't worded particularly clearly).

Comment: @Paul From what I read, (quoting) "and operations (add, multiply, divide) on < log(n) bit numbers can be done is constant time.", so each cycle of my for is constant time, I need to do n^1/2*n^1/2 xor == "n" xor, so my solution is O(kn) that is like O(n).

Comment: @xanatos you have a loop to 8. To work for all ints (rather than just for ints between 0 and 256), this has to be a loop to log(n).

Comment: @Paul Mine was an example. I'm even using uint, so it's max 32 bits. The question wasn't language-specific, and mine was a simple implementation. I'm quite sure the question was "homework", and it isn't something that will be used in the new Skynet :-) It's a "proof of concept". Oli Charlesworth solution is much better (but if I was a teacher, THIS solution I would believe that a random student could do it, Charlesworth's one? bwahahahaha)

Comment: @xanatos It's not because your answer isn't beautiful, whether the code could be written by a random student, or what a teacher believes. It fails to be O(n) and is therefore incorrect. It's not correct to argue that n is limited to 2^32 or 2^64 (otherwise all algorithms are O(1)).

Comment: @Paul Mmmh... Now I see... It's right... I do log(n^1/2) cycles for each xor. Each one is in k constant time. You are right. Still the "RAM MODEL" could imply that the maximum n is fixed, otherwhise you could have an "infinite" table. But yes, I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

if the two are not equal, then they are xor.

```
xorBits(bit1,bit2){
     return bit1 != bit2?1:0
}

xorBooleans(boolean1,boolean2){
    return boolean1 != boolean2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let k be the smallest power of 2 greater than or equal to sqrt(n). k is still O(sqrt(n)) so this won't change the complexity.

To construct the full k by k table, we construct it one row at a time.

We start with the 0th row: this is easy, because 0 xor j = j.

```
for i in xrange(k):
    result[0][i] = i
```

Next, we go over the rows in gray-code order. The gray-code is a way of counting every number from 0 to one-less than a power of 2 by changing one bit at a time.

Because of the gray-code property, we're changing the row number by 1 bit, so we have an easy job computing the new row from the old since the xors will only change by 1 bit.

```
last = 0
for row in graycount(k):
    if row == 0: continue
    bit_to_change = find_changed_bit(last, row)
    for i in xrange(k):
        result[row][i] = flip_bit(result[last][i], bit_to_change))
    last = row
```

We need some functions to help us here. First a function that finds the first bit that's different.

```
def find_changed_bit(a, b):
    i = 1
    while True:
        if a % 2 != b % 2: return i
        i *= 2
        a //= 2
        b //= 2
```

We need a function that changes a bit in O(1) time.

```
def flip_bit(a, bit):
    thebit = (a // bit) % 2
    if thebit:
        return a - bit
    else:
        return a + bit
```

Finally, the tricky bit: counting in gray codes. From wikipedia, we can read that an easy gray code can be obtained by computing xor(a, a // 2).

```
def graycount(a):
    for i in xrange(a):
        yield slow_xor(a, a // 2)

def slow_xor(a, b):
    result = 0
    k = 1
    while a or b:
        result += k * (a % 2 == b % 2)
        a //= 2
        b //= 2
        k *= 2
    return result
```

Note that the slow_xor is O(number of bits in a and b), but that's ok here since we're not using it in the inner loop of the main function.