# algorithm to calculate AND

Tags: algorithm

I want to calculate AND of numbers from 0 to `(n)^{1/2} - 1` with each of the numbers from 0 to `(n)^{1/2} - 1`. I want to do this in `O(n)` time and can't use the XOR, OR, AND operations.

Specifically, can I calculate `X+1 AND Y` if I know `X AND Y`?

P.S. - RAM model is being assumed here and operations (add, multiply, divide) on `< log(n)` bit numbers can be done is constant time.

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056949/algorithm-to-calculate-xor but not actually a duplicate.

Comment: i love the smell of homework in the morning.

Comment: Are we allowed to use a lookup table?  How big can it be?

Comment: @oil charlesworth Yeah. O(n) sized table is allowed. But building it should be possible in O(n) time

Comment: @Nitin: So, "no" then!  What you've just described is no lookup table and O(n) storage complexity!

Comment: @Albin: Close enough. The OP can add more logic operators there, they use the same restraints.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - I am sorry for not being clear. I meant O(n) words .. effectively O(n.log(n)) space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Start with a [1x1] grid:

```
H(-1) = [ 0 ]
```

Then apply the recursion:

```
H(i) = [ H(i-1)  H(i-1)
         H(i-1)  H(i-1)+(1 << i) ]
```

where that denotes matrix concatenation.  i.e. each recursion doubles the size of the grid in each dimension.  Repeat until you achieve the required size.

Comment: Is the determinant of matrix our answer according to you?

Comment: @Nitin: No, the whole matrix is the answer!  You were after a 2D array of results, right?

Comment: ohk ..so H(i-1)+(1 << i) means H(i-1)+ 1 shifted to left by i X Identity matrix?

Comment: @Nitin: Yes, I guess my notation wasn't amazingly clear.  But that's what I meant!